# MS Access 2016 -- Expose Values From Foreign-Keyed Table As Native Table Fields?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I see that, when building an MS Access table *(let's call it "Person")*, I can use the "lookup" tab of the definition of a field that I intend to have act as a foreign key to another table's primary key to specify a user-friendly UI for the "Datasheet View" of "Person".

In other words, if the field I'm building in "Person" is "CompanyID," I can make its user interface show both "ID" and "Name" from the "Company" table in a drop-down to facilitate data entry into this field.

I also see that, when building an MS Access table, I can make use of "expressions" to add a calculated field to a table -- but the expression editor only lets me reference other fields within the same table.  *(In other words, it's good for things like concatenating a first + last name into a full name.)*

Finally, I know that I can use "Relationships" to specify the PK-FK relationship between "Person" and "Company" on Person.CompanyId & Company.Id, and then build a query that exposes info like Person.FirstName, Person.LastName, Company.Name, and Company.Country, and then build a bunch of "form" & "report" infrastructure on top of that query.

However, my current project involves refactoring an existing database that has a lot of infrastructure built up over the "Person" table, and I'd like to avoid extra work for myself if I can.

The database's users want quick-reference access to view company details like "Company Country" while skimming "Person" records *(presuming Person.CompanyId is filled in with a value from Company.Id)*.

Is there any way, in Access 2016, that I can create a field called "CompanyCountry" *(read-only is fine -- preferred, in fact)* directly on the "Person" table that exposes the value of Company.Country *(with some sort of graceful failure like a null if Person.CompanyId doesn't actually resolve to a real Company.Id value)*?

Comment: Avoid [calculated fields](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html) and [lookup fields](http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm) use queries! Always use forms (you can show it like a table with datasheet view) and reports for user data access, so you can use code and events control user actions. This is worth the minimal addional effort.

Comment: I agree about not setting lookups in table, especially when the lookup involves an alias - I prefer to see the actual value saved. To answer your question simply - No. Build queries and forms. Build comboboxes on forms. Users should not work directly with tables and queries, only forms and reports.

Comment: You can set the lookup to a combobox - but no matter how smart this may seem, it is not smart, only a source for potential and serious trouble. Listen to @BitAccesser and June7.